# Elasticsearch - How to do a partial match from your query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-net, nosql

I am a bit new to Elasticsearch and I am wondering how it is possible to do a partial match of a query on a particular filed.

Lets say I have a field called "department" and it has a value "accounting". So when I search for something like "The accounting", I should be able to get the result.

eg:- Below are my two documents:

```
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "department": "finance"
},
{
   "name": "Matt",
   "department": "accounting"
}
```

My search query on the field `department` is `The accounting` or `The accounting department` and my expected result should be:

```
{
   "name": "Matt",
   "department": "accounting"
}
```

UPDATE:

@Russ Cam: The Standard analyzer removes all the punctuation and special characters so what if I have the value in the field department saved as `dept/accounting` and when i search for `dept: the dept/accounting` I should get those documents that have the department value as `dept/accounting`.

I don't want ES to give me documents with the department as `dept/accounting` when someone searches for `dept` or `accounting`. Is this possible?

Assume that the following are my documents in ES:

```
{
   "name": "Matt",
   "department": "dept/accounting"
},
{
   "name": "Kate",
   "department": "dept"
},
{
   "name": "Adam",
   "department": "accounting"
}
```

The user searches for `dept` and he gets:

```
{
  "name": "Kate",
  "department": "dept"
}
```

When the user searches for `blah blah dept/accounting blah` he should get only this:

```
{
   "name": "Matt",
   "department": "dept/accounting"
}
```

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261677/how-to-match-a-single-word-from-a-search-query-in-elasticsearch/46261842#46261842

Answer (score 0):

By default Elasticsearch is supporting the best match approach and the default Boolean operator is the `OR`. This should work out-of-the-box with for example the `Query String` query, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I have a field called `department` and my query is something like `test accounting works` and I should get the expected document (Mentioned in my question). That is, the value in the field should match any word in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried match query ,this should work for you

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "department": "accounting"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nope, my query would be something like `The accounting` or `The accounting department`.

So it would look something like this:

`{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "department": "The accounting department"
    }
}` and I am expecting to get a result like this: `{
   "name": "Matt",
   "department": "accounting"
}`.

Comment: POst your mapping for field department

Comment: @DOTNETFX if the `department` field is mapped as a `text` datatype using the default standard analyzer, then a `match` query with your example would work.

Comment: Could you guys please check my updated question? Thanks.