# How to match a single word from a search query in Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, nest

Lets say I have a field called `complexId` and it has a value with special characters: `fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango`. So when I search for something like `Complex ID fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango`, I should be able to get the result.

What I want is, I want elastic search to match at least one among these 3 words:

```
1. Complex 
2. ID 
3. fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango
```

eg:- Below are my two documents:

```
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "complexId": "fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango"
},
{
   "name": "Matt",
   "complexId": "car/35.6a5/chevy.20"
}
```

The user searches for something like `blah blah blah fruit/1a445/mango blah blah` and he should get the below result:

```
{
   "name": "Matt",
   "complexId": "fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango"
}
```

I tried this but it fails to give me any result:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
          "match" : 
          {
              complexId : "blah blah blah fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango blah blah"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The field `complexId` has a standard Analyzer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Standard Analyzer would not work in your case.

Since you are having special characters, it will be ignored while storing into ElasticSearch. Try using the `whitespace` Analyzer instead.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "whitespace",
  "text": "blah blah blah fruit/1a.445/2.10.mango blah blah"
}
```

Play around with different Analyzers and find the one that is best suited for your needs.

You could create your own custom Analyzer as well.